# Iterate two dataframes, compare and change a value in pandas or pyspark

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I am trying to do an exercise in pandas.

I have two dataframes. I need to compare few columns between both dataframes and change the value of one column in the first dataframe if the comparison is successful.

Dataframe 1:

```
Article    Country   Colour    Buy
Pants      Germany   Red       0
Pull       Poland    Blue      0
```

Initially all my articles have the flag 'Buy' set to zero.
I have dataframe 2 that looks as:

```
Article    Origin    Colour   
Pull       Poland    Blue    
Dress      Italy     Red
```

I want to check if the article, country/origin and colour columns match (so check whether I can find the each article from dataframe 1 in dataframe two) and, if so, I want to put the flag 'Buy' to 1.

I trying to iterate through both dataframe with pyspark but pyspark daatframes are not iterable.
I thought about doing it in pandas but apaprently is a bad practise to change values during iteration.

Which code in pyspark or pandas would work to do what I need to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`merge` with an `indicator` then `map` the values. Make sure to `drop_duplicates` on the merge keys in the right frame so the merge result is always the same length as the original, and rename so we don't repeat the same information after the merge. No need to have a pre-defined column of 0s.

```
df1 = df1.drop(columns='Buy')
df1 = df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates().rename(columns={'Origin': 'Country'}), 
                indicator='Buy', how='left')
df1['Buy'] = df1['Buy'].map({'left_only': 0, 'both': 1}).astype(int)
```

---

```
  Article  Country Colour  Buy
0   Pants  Germany    Red    0
1    Pull   Poland   Blue    1
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. Now I have to do something more complicated for another database but I will open another qq.